Object tracking with yolov9 is producing an unopenable video file
I am trying to use the yolo9c object detection model: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/yolov9-faster-more-accurate-object-detection-with-revolutionary-techniques-1ef428d3950e
The purpose of my script is to identify the person that takes the most space in any given frame and reframe the video the video with that person in the center. I've eliminated a few sources of error (as far as I can tell) including [1] no person detected and [2] video encoding.
[1]: The output shows instances of people detected: 0:
384x640 1 person, 1 bottle, 1 cup, 1 chair, 2 potted plants, 4 books, 478.6ms
Speed: 2.7ms preprocess, 478.6ms inference, 1.2ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
10
and [2] I've encoded the video a number of ways but none of them seem to work.
Would love any insight or direction! Thanks in advance:
import subprocess
import numpy as np
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

model = YOLO('yolov9c.pt')
video_path = 'test/test.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

# Output video resolution
output_width = 1080
output_height = 1920

# Output video file
output_video_path = 'output_video.mp4'

# OpenCV properties for video
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Command for ffmpeg to write the reframed video
ffmpeg_cmd = ['ffmpeg',
              '-y',
              '-f', 'rawvideo',
              '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
              '-s', f'{output_width}x{output_height}',
              '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
              '-r', str(fps),
              '-i', '-',
              '-c:v', 'libx264',
              '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
              output_video_path]

# Open ffmpeg process
ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    print("10")  # Print "10" for each frame

    # Perform inference
    results = model(frame)

    # Extract bounding box coordinates and confidence scores
    xyxy = results[0].boxes.xyxy.tolist()
    conf = results[0].boxes.conf.tolist()

    # Find person bounding box with the largest area
    largest_area = 0
    largest_box = None
    for box, c in zip(xyxy, conf):
        if box[-1] == 0:  # Class index 0 represents person
            box_area = (box[2] - box[0]) * (box[3] - box[1])
            if box_area > largest_area and c[0] > 0:
                largest_area = box_area
                largest_box = box

    if largest_box is not None:
        print("Largest box found:", largest_box)  # Print the largest_box if it's not None

        # Calculate center of the largest person bounding box
        center_x = int((largest_box[0] + largest_box[2]) / 2)
        center_y = int((largest_box[1] + largest_box[3]) / 2)

        # Calculate offset to center the person in the output frame
        offset_x = max(0, int(center_x - output_width / 2))
        offset_y = max(0, int(center_y - output_height / 2))

        # Reframe the video with the person centered
        reframed_frame = frame[offset_y:offset_y + output_height, offset_x:offset_x + output_width]

        # Convert the frame to bytes and write to ffmpeg process stdin
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(reframed_frame.tobytes())

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

print("Finished writing")

# Close ffmpeg process stdin
ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()

# Wait for ffmpeg process to finish
ffmpeg_process.wait()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Tl;dr
Using yolo9c object tracking model which produces an output mp4 file. However, the output file cannot be opened by any video player because of 'compatibility issues'
